# R package:s spatstat.explore and spatstat.model need spatstat.random 2.2.0.7 but not available?

Tags: r, installation, spatstat

I try to install from github spatstat.explore and spatstat.model but this does not work because spatstat.random 2.2.0.7 is needed. I cannot find the latter. Is the development not yet finalised?

Comment: Or maybe a typo? The latest version on [GitHub](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat.random) is `2.2.0.5`, there is nothing newer on the [spatstat repo](https://spatstat.r-universe.dev/ui#package:spatstat.random) either. Probably worth reporting this as an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These packages were created only a week ago, and are still in development.